# Can IFNULL be used with select statements for a sum?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with a decimal value, using the following statement I can add them all up and get the total.

```
SELECT(
(SELECT SUM(total) from recruitment where quote_id = 1)
+
(SELECT SUM(cost) from cost WHERE quote_id = 1)
)AS total
```

But if either select reurns null then the the total is null so I tried using ISNULL to return a 0 rather than null like this:

```
SELECT(
(IFNULL(SELECT SUM(total) FROM recruitment WHERE quote_id = 1),0)
+
(IFNULL(SELECT SUM(cost) FROM cost WHERE quote_id = 1),0)
)AS total
```

This didn't work, so I was just wondering how is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to handle the NULL then to convert that NULL to a 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) which returns its first non-null argument, and can replace the whole expression with a zero.

```
SELECT(
  COALESCE((SELECT SUM(total) FROM recruitment WHERE quote_id = 1),0)
  +
  COALESCE((SELECT SUM(cost) FROM cost WHERE quote_id = 1),0)
)AS total
```

`IFNULL()` should work the same way in this case - I suspect you may have had incorrect parentheses causing a syntax error.

```
/* Should work too. Make sure the inner SELECT is enclosed in () */
SELECT(
  IFNULL((SELECT SUM(total) FROM recruitment WHERE quote_id = 1),0)
  +
  IFNULL((SELECT SUM(cost) FROM cost WHERE quote_id = 1),0)
)AS total
```

Comment: Thanks alot they both worked, is there much of a difference between IFNULL and COALESCE?

Comment: @bdjohnson `IFNULL()` can only compare one thing and if that thing is null, return the second arg.  `COALESCE()` on the other hand can include multiple arguments and the first that isn't null gets returned. Ex:  `COALESCE(NULL,NULL,NULL,'Not NULL!')` so you can put multiple columns in it.  Also, it is more portable across different RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelBerkowski, I was not putting the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

try using

```
 SELECT(
(SELECT IFNULL((SELECT SUM(total) FROM recruitment WHERE quote_id=1),0))
+
(SELECT IFNULL((SELECT SUM(cost) FROM cost WHERE quote_id=1), 0))
)AS total
```

`IFNULL` is a construction which has to be used inside a `SELECT` statement like

```
SELECT IFNULL(expr0,expr1);
```

and will return `expr1` in case `expr0` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

use `COALESCE` before summing up.

```
SELECT ((SELECT SUM(COALESCE(total,0)) FROM recruitment WHERE quote_id = 1) +
        (SELECT SUM(COALESCE(cost,0)) FROM cost WHERE quote_id = 1)) AS TOtal
```